# "cure for the COVID-19" vs. "cure for COVID-19"

Tags: articles, definite-article

According to post *[Difference between "infected with" and "infected by"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245797/difference-between-infected-with-and-infected-by)*, "COVID-19" might be the name of that disease. Therefore, there should be a "the" before it when one mentions it, right?

> cure for **the** COVID-19

However, lots of posts use

> cure for COVID-19

[image]

Is "**the**" there obligatory, optional or unnecessary?

Comment: Okay, other than this COVID-19 matter, you should note that it should be "however" (one word) and "lots of". Also, "lots of posts" isn't really correct here.

Comment: If we were talking about a somewhat different disease, I'd say "cure for influenza" but "cure for the flu", even though "flu" means the same thing as "influenza". One might guess that long names don't get "the" but short names do. But then there's "I have the flu" versus "I have a cold." So maybe I shouldn't guess about such things.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, there may be something in what you say. After all, one could certainly be afflicted by _the lurgy_ or _the clap_, _the DTs_ or _the screaming ab-dab_.

Comment: Those links should be properly placed in the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look again at the examples you found on Google - they are not complete quotes. The one that includes the definite article "the" ends with .... because the search result is truncated.

The complete quote is:

> .... for developing a potential cure for **the Covid-19 virus**

The article is therefore for the word "virus".

- If you are using "COVID-19" as a proper noun, you don't need the article.
- If you are using "COVID-19" as an attributive noun, then use the appropriate article to whatever it is modifying, for example, "*the* COVID-19 virus", "*a* COVID-19 patient".

Comment: Ah yes, the “COronVIrus Disease 2019 virus” :p Maybe let’s not say “Covid-19 virus”?

Comment: @Laurel we're gonna keep saying hot water heater and lots of other silly things, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Laurel: This sentence should kill you: "The Covid-19 virus is also known as the SARS-CoV-2 virus." :)

Comment: @Laurel COVID-19, being a _disease_, isn't a virus, and most people wouldn't recognize the virus by name (SARS-CoV-2).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- absolutely - "the Covid-19 virus" is like saying "the virus that causes Covid-19".

Comment: It _can_ be like saying that, but alas in my experience many people think the virus is actually called that.

Comment: Thank you! When saying "a treatment for COVID-19 patients", "COVID-19" is being used as a proper noun, right?

Answer (score 10):

Use "the" only for a specific instance of the disease.

> Researchers are working on a cure for cancer. (general statement)
>   **The** cancer that ravaged her body caused her to lose 50 pounds. (specific to a person)

You would not say

> Researchers are working on a cure for **the** cancer.

Thus

> Scientists are working on a test for COVID-19.
>   Some people have recovered from COVID-19.
>   **The** COVID-19 (disease) that laid him up for a week caused him to lose his job.

Also, use "the" when the disease is an adjective:

> **The** cancer rate among men is ...

Comment: It's not this simple. We do use "the" before some disease names, such as "the flu" and "the common cold". It's ideosyncratic. There are also regional dialects where it's common to say "He has the cancer".

Comment: @Barmar I've often seen this usage with elderly people when discussing diseases. "You know, Carol's got the diabetes..."

Comment: "The COVID-19 that..." sounds comparable to "The Russia that invaded Mars", i.e. it sounds totally unnatural since it sounds like you're trying to clarify which COVID-19 or Russia you're talking about, but there's only one of each. There may be multiple instances of the disease, but in a similar way that there are multiple Russians.

Comment: @NotThatGuy hm, **the** Coronavirus is now quite widespread in **the** United States which went to **the** Moon in **the** 60s...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Not sure whether you're trying to disagree with me or not, but there's a reason to use "the" for each of those cases. In fact all of them *require* a "the". But that seems beyond the scope of this question. None of those reasons would apply to the COVID-19 or Russia examples. If you said "The United States that..." or "The 60s that..." it would sound similarly strange (although they're slightly different examples because, unlike the examples above, "the" belongs there).

Comment: @NotThatGuy There _have been_ in history and _are_ multiple Russias. "The Russia that invaded Crimea was not the Russia that I loved." How's that sound?

Comment: @EddieKal It would sound weird to say "The Russia" in "normal" usage, but it is a perfectly valid edge case to use "the" if you're directly implying there are "other" Russias. The same could apply to COVID-19. However, note that many people are infected with the *same* disease. Simply being inside some person does not imply there are other COVID-19s (which is not the same as saying there are other *instances* of the disease).

Comment: @NotThatGuy Right. I was just suggesting the Russia example might not be a good one. As for the rest, no contention there.

Comment: @NotThatGuy However, if we want to be scientifically precise, not all COVID-19 patients are infected with the _same virus_. A plurality of strains have been discovered.